# Unable to switch to the iFrame with same name but in different DIV tags of the same page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Based on the Tab selection two different views will be displayed. I am able to get the context of the Webelements in the first options, but unable to get the context for the remaining tab selection.

The problem is the iframe name is unique for the two selection but they are differntiate through DIV tabs.

Please find my html code and suggest a workaround to get the Webelement context in the DIV tag "folderProducer",

Note able to access the element "customerSearchForm:corpLastName" with default switch to statements.

[image]

Comment: From the html you've shown there, the names of the iframes are NOT unique. Hence you can't use the name to switch to the second iframe. What other ways have you attempted to switch to the second iframe?

Comment: Why couldn't you use the parent div id then drill down from there?

Comment: @MarkRowlands - I tried the below xpath combinations 
driver.switchTo().frame("FWin0");
driver.switchTo().frame("Content0");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'folderProducer')]/following::iframe")));
xpath = //div[contains(@id,'folderProducer')]/following::iframe 
xpath = //div[contains(@id,'folderProducer')]/following::iframe[1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't post the Java code you wrote, so I can't point out what went wrong exactly.

However, I don't think same id matters anyway. (But that's really bad, you should change it though)

Remember, `switchTo().frame()` has three overloads, you shouldn't be using index or name/id, but pass in the frame element itself. See [source code here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#306).

> WebDriver frame(int index); // unstable
>
> WebDriver frame(String nameOrId); // not working in your case, as they identical
>
> WebDriver frame(WebElement frameElement); // the one you want

Even `driver.findElements(By.name("content")).get(N)` is bad, as it depends on the order of elements, working but not elegant.

You can locate the frames either by parent `<div>` id attribute or by frame `src` attribute.

```java
// switch out of all frames, just in case, you might not need this line here
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

// switch to customer frame
WebElement customerFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#folderCustomer iframe"));
// alternative css locator: By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='customerSearch']")
driver.switchTo().frame(customerFrame);

// now inside customer frame, you can do stuff

// when you done, switch out of it
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

// switch to producer frame now
WebElement producerFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#folderProducer iframe"));
// alternative css locator: By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='producerSearch']")
driver.switchTo().frame(producerFrame);

// now inside producer frame, you can do stuff
```

Comment: The solution provided by you using the src* tag worked out. 

I am trying to build a common functions to switch the frames in the application. 'WebElement frameID = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[name=\'" + menuPaths[i]+ "\']")); driver.switchTo().frame(frameID);'

To navigate to this particular iframe, there are two partent iframes, those iframes src tag is not defined. Please guide me any suggestions.

Comment: @Thirumalai: That logic looks fine. What doesn't work? Still same name for those frames?

Comment: Yes, since the name of the frames are same, it did not work, its tries to look out for the field in the first instance i.e. customer search, instead of folder search.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that the elements have the same name, but rather that they are identical (even their parents have the same ID).

I would definitely bring this up with the developers of the site (the fact that two elements have the same ID...which is a big no-no on websites).

Regardless, you can do `driver.findElements(By.name("content")).get(N)` to get the Nth Iframe, and then switch to it.

Comment: Sorry, this answer made some valid points, but didn't make much sense. Are you sure you didn't misunderstand the question (or maybe I did)? Same id is a bad thing, but this doesn't affect how Selenium finds elements at all. The `iframes` have different parents, which makes them unique. Also they have different `src` attibutes, which is also enough. Why are you saying "they are identical (even their parents have the same ID)"?

Comment: Oh...I didn't see the HTML properly.  I thought that the 'folderProducer' and the 'folderCustomer' were the same IDs.  So does switching to `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#folderCustomer iframe[name='content']");` not work?

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of case Xpath is a bast way to find an element. You can differentiate both element by their Xpath.

Comment: I tried the below xpath combinations, it didn't work.  driver.switchTo().frame("FWin0"); driver.switchTo().frame("Content0"); driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'folderP‌​roducer')]/following::iframe"))); xpath = //div[contains(@id,'folderProducer')]/following::iframe xpath = //div[contains(@id,'folderProducer')]/following::iframe[1]